# Find an equation for a sinusoid - choosing the right phase

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions

I've got the following problem which is solved in this picture:
https://image.prntscr.com/image/atu-SdJ9QM_c7LShqdYf1g.png

Can somebody explain to me why the first phase we get from the first equation is not correct (phase = -pi/4), and we must calculate the other one (phase = -3pi/4)?

Comment: Your question is a labyrinth. Please explain it.

Comment: I will try my best to do so: 

So I've got a given graph, and two points: T1 (0, -1) and T2(3,0), and the amplitude(sqrt(2))..
From the first point we can get the following equation: phi = arcsin(-1/sqrt(2)), and from there phi = -pi/4.
But the thing is that is not the correct answer, the correct phi equals to -3pi/4.
And I don't understand why. Hope I explained it better

Answer (score 0):

When solving for the phase shift, the solution uses algebra and more specifically the $arcsin(x)$ function, which can have multiple outputs for the same input. From there, the author looks at the graph and realizes that the picture of the function shows that it hits the bottom most point in its period right after it starts from zero and goes rightward.

Now on the unit circle, when going in the traditional counter-clockwise direction, from which value, $\frac{-3\pi}{4}$ or $\frac{-\pi}{4}$, do you first hit the minimum value for sine and then proceed? Obviously $\frac{-3\pi}{4}$.

The first answer is not right because it does not satisfy all parts of the solution. We want it to have a certain $arcsin(x)$ value at zero, but we also want it to be right before the minimum, and the latter criterion is only considered later.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't quite understand the following part:
"Now on the unit circle, when going in the traditional counter-clockwise direction, from which value, −3π4 or −π4, do you first hit the minimum value for sine and then proceed? Obviously −3π4."

After I locate the two points on a unit circle, what do I do next to see which one is right?

Comment: One way of constructing the sin graph is to go counter-clockwise on the unit circle and map the y-value or height of triangle. In the sinusoid picture we clearly see that the local minima is right after $x=0$, meaning that from our phase shift angle we should immediately hit the minima at $\frac{3\pi}{2}$ going CCW.